# Saving matplotlib plot from another function as image but without showing the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am writing a school project in Python + Tkinter and I'm trying to make a button, which when clicked saves a plot which is created in other function (createPlot()) but without showing the actual plot. I want to avoid code repetition, therefore, I don't want to just copy the code from the createPlot() function and change the last line. Do you have any idea how to do this? I would appreciate any advice.
Here is the main part of code:

```
def createPlot():
    try:
        plt.style.use('Solarize_Light2')
        plt.plot(analyzeTotalNumOfInfected(),color='y', label='Some Label')
        plt.plot(analyzeNumOfTestsPerDay(),color='r', linestyle='--', label='another Label')
        plt.legend()
        plt.tight_layout
        plt.grid(True)
        fig = plt.gcf()
        fig.canvas.set_window_title('Window title...')
        plt.title('Plot title')
        plt.ylabel('y axis')
        plt.xlabel('x axis')
        plt.show()
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Lorem Ipsum")

    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Error2!", "Lorem Ipsum2")

def savePlot():
    fig = createPlot()
    fig.savefig(os.path.join(sFolder_path,"image.png"))
```

Comment: I have to point out that the join you are doing in the method savePlot() should look like this:  ```fig.savefig(os.path.join(sFolder_path,"image.png"))```

Comment: Is this really your code given above typo and the fact `createPlot()` does not `return` anything?

Comment: Yea thanks, os.path.join mistake corrected, probably typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your savePlot() method to this so the image names won't override:

```
from datetime import datetime

def savePlot():
    time = datetime.now().ctime().replace(" ", "")
    fig = createPlot()
    fig.savefig(os.path.join(sFolder_path, f"image@{time}.png"))
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I probably want to leave it as it is, for now,  so I don't have directory full of images while testing :D

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider con marking it as accepted so other people can reference it :)